# Where is the closest store to vault 88?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing fallout 4 and in need of caps for my vault 88. And before anyone suggest building a store the reason I want to find a store is to sell stuff so I can set up my store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atom Cat's Garage to the east near the water is the only larger settlement in the south east of the map that provides vendors (unless you add vendors to your own settlements using the perk). look for a character named Bluejay.

[image]